# compare 2 excel sheets with common key in both

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for VBA code to compare to Excel sheet in same workbook eg-Sheet1 vs Sheet2 and Sheet3 is for user to define things like Total row and columns to compare and which columns to be used to prepare key.

Contents is sheet as  like:

Column and Rows are not fixed, so if user gets option to define in sheet3 and code handles.
For preparing key - User can choose columns in sheet3
Difference for each key should be populated in Sheet4 with Key and column heard and different values like-

Sheet1

```
Column A CHDR 01234
Column B Life 01
Column C CRT abc
Column D Prem 10
Column E SA 1000
```

Sheet2

```
Column A CHDR 01234
Column B Life 01
Column C CRT abc
Column D Prem 10
Column E SA 1002
```

Key should be Column A, B, C
So difference should be populated in Sheet4 as

```
Column A Key 01234-01-abc
Column B Difference SA-1000-1002
```

This is my current code-

```
    Dim recordStatus As String
    Dim oldCell As Range
    Dim compareCell As Range
    Dim keyToCompare As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newCell As Range

    Set newCell = Worksheets("CHDR-JSYS").Range("A2")

    Do While newCell.Value <> ""

        keyToCompare = newCell.Resize(1, 26).Value                   ' copy row of cells ... one extra cell at end
        keyToCompare = Application.Transpose(keyToCompare)            ' convert to
        keyToCompare = Application.Transpose(keyToCompare)            ' single dimension array

        Set oldCell = Worksheets("CHDR-JACT").Range("A2")              ' set pointer to cell A2

        Do While oldCell.Value <> ""                               ' process all non-blank cells

            Set compareCell = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A2")   ' set pointer to cell A1

            If oldCell.Value = keyToCompare(1) Then
                If ( _
                        (oldCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = keyToCompare(2)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = keyToCompare(3)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = keyToCompare(4)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = keyToCompare(5)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = keyToCompare(6)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = keyToCompare(7)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = keyToCompare(8)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = keyToCompare(9)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = keyToCompare(10)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = keyToCompare(11)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = keyToCompare(12)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = keyToCompare(13)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = keyToCompare(14)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = keyToCompare(15)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = keyToCompare(16)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = keyToCompare(17)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = keyToCompare(18)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = keyToCompare(19)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = keyToCompare(20)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 20).Value = keyToCompare(21)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = keyToCompare(22)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = keyToCompare(23)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = keyToCompare(24)) _
                    And (oldCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = keyToCompare(25))) Then

                    recordStatus = "No Change"
                Else
                    recordStatus = "Change"
                End If

            Else
                recordStatus = "New Record"
            End If

            keyToCompare(26) = recordStatus

            For i = 1 To 25                                          ' update 5 cells in output workbook
                compareCell.Offset(0, i).Value = keyToCompare(i + 1)
            Next i

            Set oldCell = oldCell.Offset(1, 0)                ' move pointer one cell down
            Set compareCell = compareCell.Offset(1, 0)        ' this is missing from original code

        Loop
        Set newCell = newCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

But i cannot add more columns in it to compare as it gave me error "Too many lines continuations".
I have to compare more than 40-50 columns.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: *"I am looking for VBA code"* If you expect us to write that code for you, that's not how this site works. We can assist you with issues in code *you* have written on your own but we cannot write the code for you. Please show what you have tried already (and where you got stuck or errors). Reading [ask] might help to improve your question, you didn't ask one yet.

Comment: Sorry, I dint knew this. I have added my code but need some help to improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all these `And` lines you can use a loop:

```
If oldCell.Value = keyToCompare(1) Then
    recordStatus = "No Change" 'default is no change until we detect a change

    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To 24 'loop throug all values and check for a change
        If oldCell.Offset(0, c).Value <> keyToCompare(c + 1) Then
            recordStatus = "Change" 'change detected
            Exit For 'stop looping (one change is enough to change the status)
        End If
    Next c
Else
    recordStatus = "New Record"
End If
```

Adjust the loop `For c = 1 To 24` to your needs eg. column count to check.